# ADSL improvement in recent years

Tags: adsl

Currently I have a 2mb/s ADSL connection. I signed up for the service more than five years ago. Has technology improved much during that time to allow for greater speed using the same wires? The building I live in is quite old and the lines aren't very good. They weren't able to support 6mb/s service back then. Now I notice that the lowest speed offered by my telco is 10mb/s. Even that would be a serious improvement over what I have now.

Here are the stats from the modem:

> Modulation:    G.992.5 Annex A
>
> Line Attenuation (Up/Down) [dB]:   10,5 / 15,5
>
> SN Margin (Up/Down)   [dB]:    31,5 / 29,0

UPDATE: After some haggling with my telco, my connection is now 10mb/s.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by speed? bandwidth? latency? with ADSL2+ you can get up to 20mbps download, but the technology is still obsoleted by fiber

Comment: I'm actually puzzled by the ADSL2+ connection. I wonder if it was using that before. Maybe at some point the telco upgraded their equipment.

Comment: Support for ADSL will depend on where you live.  In the USA the telcos have no incentive to upgrade the copper lines & its equipment (i.e. POTS and ADSL services).  They consider wireless phone service the growth area for better profits and ROI.  For metro areas, upgrading to fiber optics is more likely than xDSL since the telco could then sell you 3 services: phone, Internet and TV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technology does continuously improve, and 5 years is a long time.  A more relevant question might be has the telco installed that equipment ?  (and as a corollary, is your terminating equipment as good as it wants).

It is also possible that your telco has/will deploy equipment in a closer cabinet so you are closer to the exchange (where the exchange is actually just a roadside cabinet).   This is becoming common where I am.

YMMV, but in my location the speed they are talking about is typically the speed of the plan, or capped access speed - but if your ADSL/ADSL2 connection can't handle it you won't get the advantage of the increased speed.